# Creating/Modifying C++ Directives Without Modifying Compiler?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to create or override a C++ directive without modifying the compiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to create or override a C++ directive without modifying the compiler?

No.

Comment: In addition to Remy’s absolutely correct answer, it might be worth mentioning that the [GNU m4 preprocessor](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html) is a useful tool for doing weird stuff to the language... with the caveat that it is probably a bad idea (and that you ought to rethink whatever has led you to consider trying to modify C++ to begin with).